# Combine different properties into one colum in #ask query in semantic mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

Is it possible to combine two properties with the same datatype into one column in an #ask query in SMW?

Suppose I have different datasets with Identifiers that are named differently:

```
#Object1
[[Has isbn::9780552145985]]

#Object2
[[Has id=83897239]]
```

I would like to combine these two in one column in an #ask query, like this:

```
{{#ask:
 [[Category:Besitz]]
 |?Has id = ID
 |?Has ISBN = ID
 |format=broadtable
}}
```

In the result I would like to have only the one column ID instead of two columns that are called
ID.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `template` format instead of `broadtable` with template like

```
{{!}}-
{{!}} {{{Has isbn|{{{Has id|}}}}}}
```

Or install *Semantic Scribunto*, use `mw.smw.ask` and `row['Has id'] or row['Has isbn']`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am not yet very firm with the templates for SMW output tables, so I had to change it to something like:
{{{2|}}} {{{3|}}}
But that way it works well for my purposes.